# Api platform json web token auth Decorator error(?)

Tags: php, api-platform.com, symfony5

i have kinda weird problem, i was reading and wanted to implement this in my code: https://api-platform.com/docs/core/jwt/

All in all i've configured Symfony securityBundle, Added authorize button in swaggerUI, and then is the problem. The decorator, ive added new file JwtDecorator.php(im using symfony5, php8 and version of api-platform is 2.6)

```
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\OpenApi;

use ApiPlatform\Core\OpenApi\Factory\OpenApiFactoryInterface;
use ApiPlatform\Core\OpenApi\OpenApi;
use ApiPlatform\Core\OpenApi\Model;

final class JwtDecorator implements OpenApiFactoryInterface
{
    public function __construct(
        private OpenApiFactoryInterface $decorated
    ) {}

    public function __invoke(array $context = []): OpenApi
    {
        $openApi = ($this->decorated)($context);
        $schemas = $openApi->getComponents()->getSchemas();

        $schemas['Token'] = new \ArrayObject([
            'type' => 'object',
            'properties' => [
                'token' => [
                    'type' => 'string',
                    'readOnly' => true,
                ],
            ],
        ]);
        $schemas['Credentials'] = new \ArrayObject([
            'type' => 'object',
            'properties' => [
                'email' => [
                    'type' => 'string',
                    'example' => 'johndoe@example.com',
                ],
                'password' => [
                    'type' => 'string',
                    'example' => 'apassword',
                ],
            ],
        ]);

        $pathItem = new Model\PathItem(
            ref: 'JWT Token',
            post: new Model\Operation(
                operationId: 'postCredentialsItem',
                tags: ['Token'],
                responses: [
                    '200' => [
                        'description' => 'Get JWT token',
                        'content' => [
                            'application/json' => [
                                'schema' => [
                                    '$ref' => '#/components/schemas/Token',
                                ],
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
                summary: 'Get JWT token to login.',
                requestBody: new Model\RequestBody(
                    description: 'Generate new JWT Token',
                    content: new \ArrayObject([
                        'application/json' => [
                            'schema' => [
                                '$ref' => '#/components/schemas/Credentials',
                            ],
                        ],
                    ]),
                ),
            ),
        );
        $openApi->getPaths()->addPath('/authentication_token', $pathItem);

        return $openApi;
    }
}
```

i saw this decorator for a second and after refresh it disappeared, endpoint is working if im testing it using postman, but i still cant see decorator and to bo honset i have no clue why. Ofc ive added it to my services.yaml file. My main problem is that i dont know why it doesn't show up, i dont get errors either.

Answer (score 0):

Missing api/config/packages/api_platform.yaml like describe [Documenting the Authentication Mechanism with Swagger/Open API](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/jwt/)??

Comment: Well its not missing even tho there's screen of it https://imgur.com/a/X03TSah

Comment: If your declaration in service.yaml is good try to clear the cache with rm -R var/cache/dev.

Comment: services is also good, and no difference after removing cache